# Copying files from ext4 to NTFS

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems, ntfs

I am trying to copy some files from an Ubuntu-based (ext4) external drive I have to my NTFS external drive. I opened up ext4 hard drive in Windows (it's read only) and started copy / pasting to NTFS. Two or three folders have been transferred but not all. It doesn't give me any error message or any signs to figure out what's going on. Why some files and folders are copy pasted and some not?

By the way, does this kind of transfer corrupt the files or folders by any chance? I have mostly mp3 and doc files.

Thanks a million.

Comment: Linux handles NTFS better than Windows can handle ext4... You should boot your Ubuntu installation and copy from there.

Comment: How can I open NTFS in Ubuntu though? would it let me read and copy the files?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response by the way. Very helpful.

Comment: Yes, just mount the volume and open it like normal... Ubuntu has complete R/W support for NTFS filesystems. You can do it manually via the command line, using the application called Disks (gnome-disk-utility) or perhaps directly from the Computer icon on the desktop (I use Mint Cinnamon, not Ubuntu, but there should be a rough equivalent) by just selecting the volume, right-click and select Mount.

Comment: TBH, for media I use one volume that is NTFS, and automount it in Linux... it is shared as a single repository by both Linux and Windows, that way I don't need to keep duplicate files wasting space.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this info. This is wonderful to know. I had such a terrible time going back and forth with my Windows and Ubuntu so far. If NTFS can be read and written in Ubuntu so what is the disadvantage of using it in Linux? Why not more people use NTFS and everyone recommends EXT4 instead?

Comment: Quite simply, NTFS is not native to Linux and it doesn't have the necessary features for file permissions, users, owners, groups, etc. that a native Linux filesystem does. It is generally not possible to install Linux to an NTFS filesystem.